# Django translation files substitute msgid with another translation

Tags: translation, po

I have a site that should be localized in different languages: English, French and Russian.

In russian po I have the following:

```
msgid "An error has occurred. Please reload the page."
msgstr "Произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, перезагрузите страницу."
```

In french po:

```
msgid "An error has occurred. Please reload the page."
msgstr ""
```

The problem is that my french translator doesn't know English, it knows Russian.

How to solve this problem?
Is it possible to generate french po like:

```
msgid "Произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, перезагрузите страницу."
msgstr ""
```

Thank you.

Comment: You would be better off finding an English to French translator if at all possible. Getting localization right is challenging enough without basing your translations on another translation rather than the original source texts. With exotic language combinations, this is sometimes the only available strategy, not so with EN-FR which is among the best served language pairs in the world.

Comment: In my opinion the translator must work with messages, not with ids. ID is absolutely fine to be in any language - it's supposed to be used for CTRL+F and to give tips about what's the message about. Provide him the id AND the original message (in Russian). So he will have 1) ID 2) original message to translate it into other languages. Fulfill french.po with Russian message values and let the translator translating, not inventing messages.